# Update ionic component view across app through settings page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am working on an app, which has an ionic component with the temperature of surroundings. This detail is fetched from TemperatureService I created.

Now, in the settings tab, I need the ability to change between Celcius and Fahrenheit and this change should reflect all across the app wherever the component is used.

The HTML file for the page has the component included like this :

```
<ion-col> 
        <app-temperature-meter></app-temperature-meter>
</ion-col>
```

And the temperature is fetched from service in this way :

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.loadedEnvironment = this.currentPlace.getEnvironment();
    this.temperatureToShow = this.tempCtrl.toCurrentUnit(this.loadedEnvironment.currTemp);
  }
```

where `tempCtrl` is the service and `toCurrentUnit()` converts the input temperature to the temperature in current units (C or F).

The problem here is that since the `temperatureToShow` is determined during `ngOnInit`, it does not dynamically change when I change the settings in my settings page.

Already Tested : 
Since this component is used on multiple pages, I have checked the correct functioning of the service and `ngOnInit` function. They seem to work (ie. if a page is loaded the first time and `ngOnInit` is called, the temperature shown is in the currently required units)

Expectations : 
Is there something similar to `ionViewWillEnter` for components, such that whenever they are on the screen, I can check for the current temperature units from service and change the view accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can reach your goal by publishing a message with a event emitter. If you change the settings in your setting-page publish a message over the event. The component will subscribe the message and set the new value.

Here a example for a event-emitter:

```
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';

// first page (publish an event when a user is created)
constructor(public events: Events) {}
createUser(user) {
  console.log('User created!')
  this.events.publish('user:created', user, Date.now());
}


// second page (listen for the user created event after. 
function is called)
    constructor(public events: Events) {
  events.subscribe('user:created', (user, time) => {
    // user and time are the same arguments passed in. 
`events.publish(user, time)`
    console.log('Welcome', user, 'at', time);
  });
}
```

I think with this approach the update-problem is solved.